# How can I print values of a key in sorted order in a multimap

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, multimap, equal-range

I need to design a data structure that basically stores key-value pairs with key being an integer and its value a string.

Condition 1: There could be multiple values associated with a Key.

Condition 2: I need to print all the keys stored in this map in descending order.

Condition 3: Though the Keys(integers) are printed in Descending order, their corresponding values(strings) must be printed in lexicographic(sorted in ascending) order.

**Sample Input:**

```
78 Eve                                      
99 Bob                                       
78 Alice
```

**Expected Output:**

```
99 Bob
78 Alice
78 Eve
```

Notice the keys are in descending order, while the values are in ascending order.

To do this I have come up with below code in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int N;
    string name;
    int marks;
    multimap<int, string, greater<int>> studMap;
    multimap<int, string, greater<int>>::iterator itBeg, itEnd;
    typedef multimap<int, string, greater<int>>::iterator mapIter;

    cin >> N;   // total no. of key-value pairs input by user

    while (N--)
    {
        cin >> name >> marks;  // pairs of value-key input by user - N times
        studMap.insert(pair<int, string>(marks, name));
    }

    for (itBeg = studMap.begin(); itBeg != studMap.end(); itBeg = itEnd)
    {
        marks = itBeg->first;

        pair<mapIter, mapIter> keyRange = studMap.equal_range(marks);

        for (itEnd = keyRange.first; itEnd != keyRange.second; ++itEnd)
        {
            cout << marks << " " << itEnd->second << endl;
        }
    }  
    return 0;
}
```

But I am getting output as shown below:

```
99 Bob
78 Eve 
78 Alice
```

whereas I need pair(78, Alice) to be printed before (78, Eve)

Comment: Do you need to support lookup by key, or just the operations described above? Also, are there any time bounds on how efficiently you need to be able to do this?

Comment: @templatetypedef We do need to lookup by key..the efficient it is, d better it is.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use multimap.  I'd use a `map<int, set<string>>`.  The reason is you need both your keys and values sorted.  A multimap is only going to sort the keys.  By using a map of sets, the map will sort by keys and the set will sort by values (assuming you give it the right comparator).

Comment: this is probably easiest, but a multimap with a custom compare would do it too...

Comment: No it wouldn't.  The compare function is just passed the two keys to compare, not the keys and the values.  If you're suggesting compare look up the values-  ewww, that would be horrible performance.  Or depending on implementation an inifinite recursion and stackdump.

Comment: well, i was suggesting something a hair more hack-ish i suppose... along the lines of the custom compare could access the data itself for both components.  i'm sure outside the scope of the learning exercise...

Comment: @GabeSechan I modified my code to use the map<int, set<string> > approach. All seems fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to sort key-value pairs by both the key and the value, then you don't want a multimap, which doesn't provide any way to sort on values with the same key. You want a set of pairs, with a custom comparison function that sorts them in the order you want. Something like this (warning, code written off the top of my head, not tested):

```
using KeyValue = std::pair<int, std::string>;

struct CompareKeyValue {
    bool operator()(const KeyValue& lhs, const KeyValue& rhs) const {
        if (lhs.first != rhs.first)
            return lhs.first > rhs.first; // Reverse order
        else
            return lhs.second < rhs.second;
    }
};

std::set<KeyValue, CompareKeyValue> my_data;
```

Comment: although that doesn't allow for non-unique keys... wait, why doesn't multimap work with custom compare?  the compare needs to point to something that contains both aspects is all...

Comment: It does allow for non-unique keys. It doesn't allow for non-unique key-value pairs, but if you want that, just use a multiset instead of a set. You can't give a multimap a comparison that looks at both key and value, it won't compile.

Comment: The bigger problem to me is that if you need to check if there is any value for a given key, you can't.  You can only check if a given pair is in the data structure.